# Symfony2 + FOS OAuth bundle testing without authentication

Tags: symfony, phpunit, fosoauthserverbundle

I have application which base on logging users by `FOSOAuthServerBundle` and I want to test actions in this application.

So... In Sf2 are special config file for testing environment, `config_test.yml` and I've put this code:

```
security:
    firewalls:
        default:
            anonymous: ~
```

In theory it should solve my problem, because this firewall allows anyone access any action. I've put it in `config_test.yml`, so it should work only then I'm testing application. Good solution, I was thinking.

But Sf threw this error:

> You are not allowed to define new elements for path "security.firewalls". Please define all elements for this path in one config file.

**My questions is:**
How can I allow access actions without logging while testing application by PHPUnit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add/define new elements but you can modify them.

In `config_test.yml` instead default firewall use name of your real firewall used in `security.yml`.

And better will be using `http_basic: ~` instead `anonymous: ~` so your tests will can behave like real authenticated user.

Nice cookbook here: http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/cookbook/testing/http_authentication.html

Comment: It works, thank you. In my case - I use FOSOAuthServerBundle http_basic wont work - in prod config I have `anonymous: false` and should also overwrite it.